# Nuxt.js Fetching Data only on Server Side

Tags: javascript, authentication, nuxt.js

Is there any way to fetch data from an API only on Server-Side in NuxtJS since I will include my `API_TOKEN` in the headers of the request.

**Example Code:**

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>Data fetched using asyncData</h1>
    <ul>
      <li v-for="mountain in mountains" :key="mountain.title">
        <NuxtLink
          :to="{ name: 'mountains-slug', params: { slug: mountain.slug } }"
        >
          {{ mountain.title }}
        </NuxtLink>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  async asyncData({ $http }) {
    const mountains = await $http.$get('https://api.nuxtjs.dev/mountains', {headers: "X-API-KEY: MY_API_TOKEN"})
    return { mountains }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: This token is private or public?

Comment: It is private token. That's why I want to make the request on server side so that users don't see the token

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use private keys here because you will reach your server only once, then it will be used only on the client. Either use a middleware to hide the token or use a public one.

My [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69575243/8816585) on this subject can be useful here.